# I want to send Textview values to Firebase database with Chechkbox

Tags: android

I want to store `Textview` value to Firebase database with `Checkbox` value. But only `Checkbox` values to going to fire base database, not `Textview` values going. i want to store `Textview` (name) to fire base with absent, present `Checkbox`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
// Is the view now checked?
boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

// Check which checkbox was clicked
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.checkbox_meat:
        if (checked)
          FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference("Data").push().setValue(chechbox_meat);
        else
            // Remove the meat
        break;
    case R.id.checkbox_cheese:
        if (checked)
            // Cheese me
        else
            // I'm lactose intolerant
        break;
    // TODO: Veggie sandwich
}
```

}